# Method that always return null

Tags: java, c#, null, nullreferenceexception

I'm stuck with a piece of a code I'm translating from Java to C#.

Basically, I have a Map(Dictionary) with keys composed by Pair and Values represented by a class made by me (Square); in this class there's only one field, which is Optional (yes, I create the Optional class in C#).

At the beginning I fill this Dictionary with pairs to make a simil-grid and empty Optional, as you can see in the code below.

```
class World
{
    private Dictionary<Pair<int, int>, Square> map = 
        new Dictionary<Pair<int, int>, Square>();

    public World(int width, int height)
    {
        this.size = new Pair<int, int>(width, height);
        for (int w = 0; w < this.size.GetX(); w++)
        {
            for (int h = 0; h < this.size.GetY(); h++)
                this.map.Add(new Pair<int, int>(w, h), 
                    new Square(Optional<Entity>.Empty()));
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the Square class

```
class Square
{
    private Optional<Entity> entity;

    public Square (Optional<Entity> entity)
    {
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    public Optional<Entity> GetEntity() 
    {
        return this.entity;
    }

    public void SetEntity(Optional<Entity> entity)
    {
        this.entity = entity;
    }
}
```

Here's the problem, this function below **always** returns null when I try to get an existent value from the Dictionary, it throws  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
In this code I cut away all the controls, but I know that I try to get a value already inserted; also, I tried to run Dictionary.ContainsValue and it return false! But I do have inizialed the Dictionary.

```
public Square? GetSquare(int x, int y)
{
    if (y < this.size.GetY() && y >= 0 && < x this.size.GetX() && x >= 0)
    {
        this.map.TryGetValue(new Pair<int, int>(x, y), out Square? square);
        return square;
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("no square in this position!");
}
```

I leave here the code of the Optional class too, but I'm almost 100% sure that it's not the problem

```
public class Optional<T>
{
    private T value;
    public bool IsPresent { get; set; } = false;

    private Optional() { }

    public static Optional<T> Empty()
    {
        return new Optional<T>();
    }

    public static Optional<T> Of(T value)
    {
        Optional<T> obj = new Optional<T>();
        obj.Set(value);
        return obj;
    }

    private void Set(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.IsPresent = true;
    }

    public T Get()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

This is Pair class

```
    public class Pair<X, Y>
    {
        private X first;
        private Y second;

        public Pair(X first, Y second)
        {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
        }
        public X GetX()
        {
            return this.first;
        }

        public Y GetY()
        {
            return this.second;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "<" + first + "," + second + ">";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `Pair<,>`? It might have a bad `GetHashCode` or `Equals` implementation. It probably would be better to use a value tuple for the key instead (i.e. `(int, int)`).

Comment: With `this.map.TryGetValue(new Pair<int, int>(x, y), out Square? square);` you'll never get any result unless `Pair` is a struct type. This wouldn't work in Java either I'm pretty sure. Look at the logic in that line: "give me the value associated with this `new` object" - since this object is new, no value would be associated with it

Comment: `new Pair<int, int>(x, y)` will *not* match an existing dictionary key unless you've overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in the `Pair` class. The default behavior is to use reference comparison to determine equality, and a `new` *anything* will not reference-match something else. Please show the `Pair` class code for help with an actual answer.

Comment: Your `Pair<X,Y>` is insufficient for your use case. Without implementing `GetHashCode` and `Equals`, what Rufus L described is exactly what's happening. Again, I'll suggest using a value tuple, `(int,int)` (which is `ValueTuple<int,int>`, *not* `Tuple<int,int>`), as your key. It implements those methods correctly (requiring that the types *in* the tuple also implement it correctly, of course, which `int` does).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved it.
The problem was, as you said, the Pair class.
I substitute it with the ValueTuple<> class and now everything works fine, still thanks.